# Save Matrix of RGB values as image

Tags: julia

let's say I have

```
c = RGB{Normed{UInt8,8}}[
        RGB{N0f8}(1.0,1.0,1.0) RGB{N0f8}(0.0,0.502,0.0) RGB{N0f8}(1.0,0.0,0.0);
        RGB{N0f8}(1.0,0.0,0.0) RGB{N0f8}(1.0,1.0,1.0) RGB{N0f8}(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        RGB{N0f8}(0.0,0.502,0.0) RGB{N0f8}(0.0,0.0,0.0) RGB{N0f8}(0.0,0.502,0.0)]
```

How can I save this as a image in e.g. PNG or JPG format?

Note that I don't just need 9 pixels of those colors but like a bigger picture. Like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `save` function from `Images.jl`package (you should also install `FileIO.jl` and `ImageMagick.jl` for necessary transformations). To save it as a bigger picture you should manually resize the array to the required size with the help of `repeat` function

```
using Images

c = RGB{Normed{UInt8,8}}[
        RGB{N0f8}(1.0,1.0,1.0) RGB{N0f8}(0.0,0.502,0.0) RGB{N0f8}(1.0,0.0,0.0);
        RGB{N0f8}(1.0,0.0,0.0) RGB{N0f8}(1.0,1.0,1.0) RGB{N0f8}(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        RGB{N0f8}(0.0,0.502,0.0) RGB{N0f8}(0.0,0.0,0.0) RGB{N0f8}(0.0,0.502,0.0)]

c2 = repeat(c, inner = (50, 50))

save("/tmp/test.png", c2)
```

Here 50x50 in `c2` definition is the size of a single cell in pixels.

Comment: That's what I just ended up doing now. :) Got a custom repeat like function, thanks for pointing that out!